# Misleading warning in Error Stripe side bar in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm currently using Intellij Idea (v2020.2) to code and today I encountered this wild warning as shown below.

[image: Misleading warning in Intellij]

Is there any ideas to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `<Object>` to `<>`. Diamond operator was introduced in Java 1.7